# Convergence of subsequence of partial sums implies full convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Define $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j$ a sum of real numers.

Suppose there is a subsequence such that $S_{n_j} \to S$ for some $S$, i.e., the infinite sum converges along this subsequence. Does this imply that $S_n$ converges too?

It seems like it should, since it's simply an index which is increasing but there may be a counterexample I can't think of..

Comment: If all the terms $a_j$ are positive, then it is true.  Since $S_n$ is then an increases sequence which converges if and only if it is bounded, if and only if a subsequence is bounded (since it's increasing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if e.g. $a_j = (-1)^j$ then $S_{2k} = 0$ for all $k$ but the series itself does not converge.

Comment: If it is Cauchy I think it does.

Comment: @Johan   The sequence $S_n$ is not cauchy.  It's $-1$ for odd indexes, and $0$ for even indexes.  Cauchy sequence must have elements that get close to each other.

Comment: @maddib I know it was just a remark to the case when it holds.

Comment: @Johan  Understood.

Comment: @Johan do you mean when $a_n$ are cauchy?  Because even that doesn't work (if you are only asking about arbitrary subsequencs), you can just take $a_j$ to be $n^2$ copies of $1/n^2$ and then $n^2$ copies of $-1/n^2$, etc...  [edit: Actually, now I think about it, I think you meant when $S_n$ are cauchy and you have a convergent subsequence, which is true]

Comment: Isn't it true if you have $a_j \rightarrow 0$ and $S_{2n}$ converges (ie, only consider subsequences that have a bounded distance from one index to the next)

Comment: Yes, it's true if $a_j\to0$ and $S_{2n}$ converges.